# Posterous api php curl

Tags: php, api, curl, posterous

Anyone see anything wrong with this, it is not working and its returning null.

```
$request = array(
  "api_token" => $token,
  "name" => null,
  "byline" => "via api",
  "owner_id" => null,
  "id" => $id,
  "raw_theme" => $t,
  "friendly_name" => "Test"
);


$session = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: What is the output of `curl_error($session)` and `curl_errno($session)` ?

Comment: The output for both is nothing.

Comment: What is the value of your `$url` variable?

Comment: `http://posterous.com/api/2/sites/$SITE_NAME/theme`

Comment: If you change your user or pass do you get a `HTTP Basic: Access denied.` response?

Comment: what is output of curl_getinfo($session); before curl_close

Comment: When I test your code on site locked with a `.htaccess` file it works just fine.

Comment: I dont have any sort of `.htaccess` running, what do you mean by locked?

Comment: @ThomasReggi - I just meant that the code seems fine=) Try setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to true and check the response.

Comment: @KristerAndersson the response is 200 and should be 201 =[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but if I try to send a create new theme request from https://posterous.com/api then the post parameters are named like:

```
theme[byline]
theme[designer_url]
theme[friendly_name]
theme[raw_theme]
theme[thumb]
```

So, perhaps you should try changing your code into something like:

```
$request = array(
  "api_token" => $token,
  "name" => null,
  "theme[byline]" => "via api",
  "owner_id" => null,
  "id" => $id,
  "theme[raw_theme]" => $t,
  "theme[friendly_name]" => "Test"
);
```

Also, I don't see any `owner_id`, `name` or `id` parameters in their example.

Comment: Oh man I just did this and was about to post update, thanks!!